# Concatenar dos filas donde el nombre de una tabla es una palabra reservada

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

estoy tratando de ejecutar una consulta donde debo concatenar el valor "lat" y "long", pero tengo error con la palabra "long"

A continuación muestro la consulta con la que tengo problemas:

```
mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");
$peticion = "SELECT CONCAT (lat, '/', 'long') as coord, name, description FROM `locations`";            
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $peticion);

while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {

       $html='<tr id="tabla_est">
       <td>'.$fila['name'].'</td> 
       <td>'.$fila['description'].'</td>
       <td>'.$fila['coord'].'</td> 
       </tr>';
       echo $html;}
```

Si dejo la petición como se encuentra arroja los resultados como los necesito, con la excepción de que en la fila 'coord' muestra este resultado **4.925806/long** donde reemplaza el valor numérico por la palabra en cuestión.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Que pasa cuando remueves las comillas?

Comment: @alanfcm, ¿De la palabra reservada? Arroja este error "mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in..."

Comment: Al tratarse de una palabra reservada de `sql` es posible que te genere el conflicto. Puedes cambiar el nombre del campo **_long_** por **_longitud_** tanto en la tabla como en el query y probar de nuevo con este cambio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas usar "backticks" de la misma forma que hiciste con el nombre de la tabla asi:

```
SELECT CONCAT (lat, '/', `long`) as coord, name, description FROM `locations`
```